# How to call query function in Bonfire model?

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

Customers_model

```
 Class Customers_model extends BF_Model{

 protected $table_name  = 'customers';
protected $key          = 'customer_id';
protected $date_format  = 'datetime';
```

My query function in model

```
function get_customerlist()
{
    $sql = $this->db->query('SELECT first_name, last_name , customer_id FROM customers ');
    return $sql->result();

}

}`
```

Controller

```
public function listCustomer()
{

    $this->load->model('customers_model'); // whatever you call it

  $data['list'] =  $this->customers_model->get_customerlist();

    $this->load->view('myview', $data);

}
```

View

```
 foreach($list as $value)
    {
        echo  $value->first_name. '<br />'; output.
    }
```

It can't show `$list` array from controller : Undefined list variable

Comment: What errors are you in your error log?

Comment: @mkaatman: Undefined variable: list

Comment: Oh, shouldn't that foreach by something like `foreach($data['list'] as $value)` it's incomplete, so I don't know what other code you've got that may be setting list but php seems to think no variable named list exists.

Comment: @mkaatman same error  Undefined variable: data

Comment: After looking at the docs, it seems like you were doing it correctly. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html If you `var_dump($data['list']);` immediately after setting it, does it contain anything?

Comment: @mkaatman still same error , have no idea why you use var_dump

Comment: var_dump will show you the contents of that variable. If that variable is empty after you set it and then you try to reference list, it's going to puke.

Answer (score 3):

In your `Model` Query method i made few changes,

```
function get_customerlist()
    {
        $selelct = array('first_name','last_name','customer_id');
        return $this->db->select($select)
                       ->from('customers')
                       ->get()
                       ->result();   
    }
```

In your Controller,

```
public function listCustomer()
 {
  $this->load->model('customers_model'); // whatever you call it
  $list = $this->customers_model->get_customerlist();
  $data['list'] =  $list; //returned result is an array of object
  $this->load->view('myview', $data);
}
```

In Your view,try this,

```
foreach((array)$list as $item)
{
     echo  $item->first_name. '<br />';
}
```

It should work.

Comment: can you just write this in your controller? echo "<pre>";print_r($list);die; after the second line...and show me what it is giving...

Comment: yeah it showed array of customer :Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [first_name] => david
            [last_name] => brime
            [customer_id] => 277
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [first_name] => tom
            [last_name] => term
            [customer_id] => 278
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [first_name] => Megan
            [last_name] => lee
            [customer_id] => 280
        )

)

Comment: very good,can you do the same in your view page,so we will sure this array of object is going to your view..put it in your view,<?= "<pre>";print_r($list);die;?>

Comment: yeah it still Undefined variable: list

Comment: please check if there is any problem regarding view name..code looks fine :)....can you attach a screenshot of your view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147296/discussion-between-molagbal-and-jenny).